# Arduino Nano TX/RX indicator LEDs

Tags: arduino, led, serial

I'm connecting an Arduino Nano to an RS485 bus via it's standard TX/RX lines, but i want the TX/RX indicator LEDs elsewhere. It looks like the standard LEDs are just connected to TX0 and RX0 directly with a series resistor and leech power of whatever is driving the communication (MAX487 in my case)?. Is it really that simple?

**Bonus question:** I want to drive one LED with both TX/RX, can this be accomplished by just putting diodes before the LEDs and then connecting the traces after both diodes together?

[image]

[image: Traces]

Comment: This should work, but I would use a larger value resistor. 1 mA is plenty with modern LEDs. One website says that the receiver load should be more than 3000 ohms, but I don't know how reliable it is. The picture you posted has 1k resistors.

Comment: arduino doesn't do that, but yours doesn't look like a genuine  arduino.

Comment: https://content.arduino.cc/assets/NanoV3.3_sch.pdf

Comment: Success may depend on the voltage levels of the Tx0 and Rx0 signals. If they are 3.3V, you will lose 0.7V through the diodes, and perhaps 1.8V for the LED, leaving just 0.8V across the resistor. That still provides 0.8/390 = 2 mA, so that should be enough. For a blue or white LED, you could use Schottky diodes.

Comment: @Juraj That uses an FT323, im not including an USB UART in my design, only ICSP and RS485.